# Invalid column name named "100% Examination charges" during pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pivot activity description with amount present in it.

My data is as follows,

```
  Sr No     Invoice Date    Invoice No    Payer Name    IGMNo    Container No    Size    Type    Act. gate in Date    Container Agent    Container  Agent  Name    Importer Name    CHA Code    CHA Name    Activity Description    Amount    Service Tax    Total                                                                  
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  1    8-1-2018 12:12:29 AM    MII180800001    SAME DEUTZ FAHR INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED    2200750    ECMU9674562    40    GB    7-26-2018 4:50:35 AM    CLC007    CMA CGM    SAME DEUTZ FAHR INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED    CHS020    SEAKING CARGO SERVICES (I)  PVT LTD    Handling &  PNR Movement Charges-FCL    10400    1872    12272 
  2    8-1-2018 12:12:29 AM    MII180800001    SAME DEUTZ FAHR INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED    2200750    ECMU9674562    40    GB    7-26-2018 4:50:35 AM    CLC007    CMA CGM    SAME DEUTZ FAHR INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED    CHS020    SEAKING CARGO SERVICES (I)  PVT LTD    100% Examination Charges              2000    360    2360
```

Please note that this worked previously for my older data. Currently I dont have older data to troubleshoot the same.

It throws an error as ""Invalid column name '100% Examination Charges'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,"

My query is as follows,

```
   DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = '',@Sql nvarchar (max)

 SET @Columns=(SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ QUOTENAME([Activity Description] )
            FROM  [dbo].[FCLParent] FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,''))


 SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[FCL_Pivot] ([Payer Name], [Container No], [Size], [Type], [CHAName], 
[Act Gatein Date], [Container  Agent  Name], [Importer Name], ' + @Columns + ')

 SELECT [Payer Name], [Container No], [Size], [Type], [CHAName], 
 [Act Gatein Date], [Container  Agent  Name], [Importer Name], ' + @Columns + '
  FROM (
  SELECT [Payer Name], [Container No], [Size], [Type], [CHAName], [Act Gatein Date],
  [Container  Agent  Name], [Importer Name], [Activity Description], [Amount]
  FROM dbo.FCLParent
  ) src
  PIVOT (MAX([Amount]) FOR [Activity Description] IN (' + @Columns + '))     pvt'
  EXEC (@sql)
```

The result of print statement is as follows,

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FCL_Pivot] ([Payer Name], [Container No], [Size],    [Type], [CHAName], 
[Act Gatein Date], [Container  Agent  Name], [Importer Name], [REEFER  ELECTRIC CHARGES],[CONTAINER GROUND RENT CHARGE],[INCREASE IN MOVEMENT CHARGES],[WEIGHMENT CHARGES],[STORAGE CHARGE],[DESTUFFING CHARGES],[PRIORITY CHARGES],[RE-WEIGHTMENT CHARGES],[SHIFTING CHARGES],[HAZARDOUS CHARGES],[LIFT ON LIFT OFF CHARGES],[VALUE ADDED CHARGES],[SEAL CHARGES],[INSURANCE CHARGES],[CONTAINER TRACKING CHARGES],[EMPTY MOVEMENT CHARGES],[CONTAINER MOVEMENT AND INCREASE CHARGES],[KALMAR HANDLING CHARGES],[HANDLING CHARGES LDD],[MONITORING CHARGES],[FUEL CHARGES],[INSPECTION CHARGES],[SSR CHARGES],[DOCUMENTATION CHARGES],[50% EXAMNIATION CHARGES],[HANDLING CHARGES],[P.O.ESCORT CHARGES],[HANDLING AND  PNR MOVEMENT CHARGES],[OOG DOCUMENTATION CHARGES],[100% EXAMINATION CHARGES],[ESCORT CRANE USAGE CHARGES])

SELECT [Payer Name], [Container No], [Size], [Type], [CHAName], 
[Act Gatein Date], [Container  Agent  Name], [Importer Name], [REEFER   ELECTRIC CHARGES],[CONTAINER GROUND RENT CHARGE],[INCREASE IN MOVEMENT CHARGES],[WEIGHMENT CHARGES],[STORAGE CHARGE],[DESTUFFING CHARGES],[PRIORITY CHARGES],[RE-WEIGHTMENT CHARGES],[SHIFTING CHARGES],[HAZARDOUS CHARGES],[LIFT ON LIFT OFF CHARGES],[VALUE ADDED CHARGES],[SEAL CHARGES],[INSURANCE CHARGES],[CONTAINER TRACKING CHARGES],[EMPTY MOVEMENT CHARGES],[CONTAINER MOVEMENT AND INCREASE CHARGES],[KALMAR HANDLING CHARGES],[HANDLING CHARGES LDD],[MONITORING CHARGES],[FUEL CHARGES],[INSPECTION CHARGES],[SSR CHARGES],[DOCUMENTATION CHARGES],[50% EXAMNIATION CHARGES],[HANDLING CHARGES],[P.O.ESCORT CHARGES],[HANDLING AND  PNR MOVEMENT CHARGES],[OOG DOCUMENTATION CHARGES],[100% EXAMINATION CHARGES],[ESCORT CRANE USAGE CHARGES]
 FROM (
 SELECT [Payer Name], [Container No], [Size], [Type], [CHAName], [Act Gatein Date],
 [Container  Agent  Name], [Importer Name], [Activity Description],  [Amount]
 FROM dbo.FCLParent
 ) src
 PIVOT (MAX([Amount]) FOR [Activity Description] IN ([REEFER ELECTRIC CHARGES],[CONTAINER GROUND RENT CHARGE],[INCREASE IN MOVEMENT CHARGES],[WEIGHMENT CHARGES],[STORAGE CHARGE],[DESTUFFING CHARGES],[PRIORITY CHARGES],[RE-WEIGHTMENT CHARGES],[SHIFTING CHARGES],[HAZARDOUS CHARGES],[LIFT ON LIFT OFF CHARGES],[VALUE ADDED CHARGES],[SEAL CHARGES],[INSURANCE CHARGES],[CONTAINER TRACKING CHARGES],[EMPTY MOVEMENT CHARGES],[CONTAINER MOVEMENT AND INCREASE CHARGES],[KALMAR HANDLING CHARGES],[HANDLING CHARGES LDD],[MONITORING CHARGES],[FUEL CHARGES],[INSPECTION CHARGES],[SSR CHARGES],[DOCUMENTATION CHARGES],[50% EXAMNIATION CHARGES],[HANDLING CHARGES],[P.O.ESCORT CHARGES],[HANDLING AND  PNR MOVEMENT CHARGES],[OOG DOCUMENTATION CHARGES],[100% EXAMINATION CHARGES],[ESCORT CRANE USAGE CHARGES])) pvt
```

**I find in some threads that @columns cannot be used in select statement(because that invalid column is present in that @columns) so this will occur. But if I remove it from select statement values are null producing all values are null, if I put into select statement this errors.**

Can someone pointout exactly what is the issue.

Comment: Please line up the Column names and Values in the first code block that shows the data.

Comment: Use `print @sql` to find the error.

Comment: While printing @sql column name was present in the query i.e(@columns). So I dont know why is this occuring?

Comment: Please post the result of the print statement.

Comment: Hi Peter B, the value which contains 100% Examination charges in the code is activity description and next column is amount where I am pivoting it

Comment: I have edited in question itself. Please check

Comment: The table [dbo].[FCL_Pivot] exists or is created dynamically? Do you have a column [100% EXAMINATION CHARGES] in destination table?

Comment: Yes FCL_Pivot is available not created dynamically. That particular columns is available in this table also.

Comment: Any help on this. couldn't able to find the error.

Comment: Note: If I remove the dynamic columns from select statement it works, but all values are throwing as Null. If i add it this error occurs.